# POX component listen to events

Tags: listener, mininet, pox

I want to discover the  topology of a network emulated by mininet using POX components. I figured out that I need to write my own component, which is listening to **LinkEvents**. Something like:

```
someObject.addListenerByName("LinkEvent", someFunction)
```

But I don't actually know on what kind of an object i should execute this.

If I execute it as

```
core.openflow_discovery.addListenerByName("LinkEvent", someFunction)
```

as stated in the **openflow.discovery** module, it throws the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'openflow_discovery' not registered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by calling `addListenerByName` from within `launch()`.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to use pox modules named "gephi" to do this, it should be under misc directory, just add this method to the "gephi_topo.py" in "class GephiTopo":

```
 def get_gephi_topology (self):
    switchesAndLinksAndHosts=[self.switches,self.links, self.hosts]
    return switchesAndLinksAndHosts
```

and then use it anywhere in your pox controller like:

```
topo=gephi_topo.GephiTopo.get_gephi_topology(core.GephiTopo)
switches= topo[0]
links=topo[1]
hosts=topo[2]
```